# Why does my server complain of 'Bad authorization header'?

Tags: flask, python-requests, boto3, amazon-cognito

I am having trouble getting my client and server for a simple AWS Cognito authorization to agree on what the token should look like.

My client uses boto3 and requests. I pass the authorization in the header which I've seen in more than half of tutorials but I've also seen use of the auth parameter which I am not using.

Here's my server:

```
from flask import request, jsonify, make_response
import flask.json
from flask_jwt_extended import (
    JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token,
    get_jwt_identity
)

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

# from: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basic_usage/
# Setup the Flask-JWT-Extended extension
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'  # Change this!
jwt = JWTManager(app)

@app.route("/auth_test")
@jwt_required
def auth_test ():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify({"current_user": "current_user"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

One clue here is that JWT_SECRET_KEY is copied from a tutorial but I'm unclear on what I need to change it to. Perhaps this is my issue but if it is I don't see the solution or what to change it to.

Here's my client:

```
import requests
import boto3

host = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
region = '...'
user_pool_id = '...'
username = '...'
password = '...'
app_client_id = '...'
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name = region)

auth_response = client.admin_initiate_auth(
    UserPoolId = user_pool_id,
    ClientId = app_client_id,
    AuthFlow = 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
    AuthParameters = {
        'USERNAME' : username,
        'PASSWORD' : password
    }
)

id_token = auth_response['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']
response = requests.get(host + "/auth_test" , headers = { 'Authorization': id_token })
print(response.json())
```

It prints:
    {'msg': "Bad Authorization header. Expected value 'Bearer '"}

This indicates that I should be passing `"Bearer " + id_token` instead of just `id_token` but this is contrary to most tutorials I've read and furthermore when I do that I still get the same error.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have made some changes due to the comments. I have added

```
app.config['JWT_ALGORITHM'] = 'RS256'
app.config['JWT_DECODE_ALGORITHMS'] = ['RS256']
#app.config['JWT_PUBLIC_KEY'] = '...' # value that I got from https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<my pool id>/.well-known/jwks.json. There were two entries I tried both values found in kid
```

RS256 matches Cognito's encoding so I think I need to set that for my server. However I now simply get this error when running the demo:

```
ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you sure you have allowed Authorization header in CORS as allowed headers ?

Comment: You can also validate your received id token on site jwt.io

Comment: Take a look at the JWT_HEADER_TYPE option here: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options/#header-options

Comment: I have made some edits based on comments and I'm still getting an error.